# Better sum between a int array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sum, max

I have this array

```
int arr = new int[] { 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 
978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 
696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 678, 678, 678, 678, 678, 678, 678, 678, 678, 678, 
446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446 };

20 elements 978
20 elements 696
10 elements 678
10 elements 446
```

I need find the best combination of sum until 6000.

Fox example:

```
978 + 978 + 978 + 978 + 696 + 696 + 696 = 6000
```

This is a best combination.

After find the best combination, I need remove the summed elements to find the best sum again.

In this case, my array will be:

```
16 elements 978
17 elements 696
10 elements 678
10 elements 446
```

Then, the next better sum will be:

```
 978 + 978 + 978 + 978 + 696 + 696 + 696 = 6000
```

Then:

```
978 + 978 + 978 + 978 + 696 + 696 + 696 = 6000
```

Then :

```
978 + 978 + 978 + 978 + 696 + 696 + 696 = 6000
```

In this moment my array is:

```
4 elements 978
8 elements 696
10 elements 678
10 elements 446
```

Now, my best sum is:

```
696 + 696 + 696 + 696 + 696 + 696 + 696 + 678 + 446 = 5996
```

And my array:

```
4 elements 978
1 elements 696
9 elements 678
9 elements 446
```

Well... and I need to do the sum until my array is empty.

Any sugestion?

Could be in js, c# or vb.

Comment: What is _best combination_? Also, what have you tried so far? Also, this looks like a 0/1-knapsack problem to me, which is NP-hard.

Comment: @alzaimar I am not entirely sure this is NP problem. I can easily think of a solution 6000 * array.length. This seems non-exponential to me.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev, would you explain your solution? Thank you.

Comment: 0/1-knapsack? NP-Hard? Sorry guys... I'm begginer.... I dont know for where start.... I need to know what is the sum of the elements of the array that is closest to 6000

Comment: @alzaimar I have posted my solution as answer to the question

Comment: just refer to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: Why, after four combinations using four of twenty highest values and three of twenty 2nd highest each can't you use a fifth? Leaving 0×978, 5×696, 
10×678 and
10×446

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution to a single iteration of your task. I will find the "best matching" combination in time `O(m * n)` where `m` is the aim number (6000 in your case) and n is the total number of elements left in the array (53 in the initial iteration). The memory complexity of my solution will be `O(m)`

I will one auxiliary notations:

- `parent[m + 1]` - storing what was the last number used to form the particular sum. Values will be -1 if the sum was not achieved yet
- `maxm` - the maximum number among `arr`
- `list<int> chosen` - the numbers chosen for the particular iteration
- `best` the best sum according to your definition

Here is a pseudocode of my solution

```
parents[i] = { -1 if i != 0; -2 otherwise} // distinguish the empty sum
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  for (j = m + maxm; j > 0; j--)
    if parents[j] == -1 && j - arr[i] >= 0 && arr[i] != -1
       parents[j] = i

// choose the best; choose only numbers with parents[i] != -1
for i = 0; i < m + maxm; i++
   if parents[m + i] != -1
      best = m + i
      break
   else if parents[m - i] != -1
      best = m - i
      break
while best != 0 
   chosen.add(best - parents[best])
   best = parents[best]
```

**EDIT** Adding calculation of `best` according to your definition.

Comment: @filipewan This is pseudocode, probably you will place in the way you initialize arrays in C#, the loops etc. I am not C# developer, do not know the language, but all of programming languages support basic operations like `for`, `while` etc.

Answer (score 0):

.. Here's my code in C#:

```
Dictionary ex = new Dictionary<Integer,Short>();

ex.Add(978, 20); // 20 elements 978
ex.Add(696, 20); // 20 elements 696
ex.Add(678, 10); // 10 elements 678
ex.Add(446, 10); // 10 elements 446
```

It's more Time-efficient to use, instead of an array of all elements, then instead of calculating sum every time, I've pre-calculated total sum:

```
class Ex
{
    Dictionary<Integer,Short> ex;
    long sum;

    public Ex ()
    {
        ex = new Dictionary<Integer,Short>();
        sum = 0;
    }

    public void add (int number, short frequency)
    {
        ex.Add(number, frequency);
        sum += (number * frequency);
    }

    public void remove (int number)
    {
        sum -= (number * ex.Get(number));
        ex.Remove(number);
    }

    public void increment (int number, short frequency)
    {
        ex.Set(number, ex.Get(number)+frequency);
        sum += (number * frequency);
    }

    public void subtract (int number, short frequency)
    {
        ex.Set(number, ex.Get(number)-frequency);
        sum -= (number * frequency);
    }

    public long getSum ()
    {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps ..

Comment: it's C#, the bottom block of code is a class you will use in the above snippet which you can apply in your main() function

Comment: Also this structure is more optimal, you can extend it to implement the algorithm you need..

Answer (score 0):

OK I don't remember how i have stumbled upon this topic but I think I have managed to find a fast algorithm to solve the problem. At least with the given data. My solution is in JS, where i feel more comfortable. It resolves in less than 7ms but i believe it can simply be transcoded into Haskell or C if needed to be faster.

OK first lest see the solution...

```js
function getSum(arr,sum){
  function getCombinations(arr){
    var len = arr.length,
       subs = Array(Math.pow(2,len)).fill();
    return subs.map((_,i) => { var j = -1,
                                k = i,
                                 res = [];
                               while (++j < len ) {
                                 k & 1 && res.push(arr[j]);
                                 k = k >> 1;
                               }
                               return res;
                             }).slice(1);
  }
  function getPossibles(a,t){
    var fo = a[0],
    maxTry = Math.min(Math.floor(t/fo.n),fo.c);

    return a.length > 1 ? Array(maxTry).fill()
                                       .map((_,i) => ({n:fo.n, c:maxTry-i}))
                                       .reduce((p,c) => (p.push(...getPossibles(a.slice(1),t-c.n*c.c).map(e => a.length > 2 ? [c,...e]
                                                                                                                            : [c,e])),p),[])
                        : [{n:fo.n, c: maxTry}];
  }
  var  hash = arr.reduce((p,c) => (p[c] ? p[c]++ : p[c] = 1,p),{}),
   condense = Object.keys(hash)
                    .reverse()
                    .map(k => ({n: k, c:hash[k]}));
     combos = getCombinations(condense);
  possibles = combos.reduce((p,c) => (c.length > 1 ? p.push(...getPossibles(c,sum))
                                                   : p.push(getPossibles(c,sum)),p),[]);
  return possibles.filter(p => p.reduce((s,o) => s += o.n*o.c,0) === sum)
                  .map(e => e.reduce((p,c) => p.concat(Array(c.c).fill(c.n)),[]));
}

var arr = [978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 978, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696 ,696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 696, 678, 678, 678, 678, 678, 678, 678, 678, 678, 678, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446, 446],
 result = [],
     ps = 0,
     pe = 0;
ps = performance.now();
result = getSum(arr,6000);
pe = performance.now();
console.log(result);
console.log("Done in:", pe-ps);
```

I tried to make the code as explicit as possible. I will try to explain step by step here.

We have a function to solve this problem called `getSum()` and in it we have two utility functions as `getCombinations()` and `getPossibles()`.

Once we receive our values array (`arr`) and the target (`sum`) first we establish a hash table under `hash` and it turns out to be like;

```
{ '446': 10, '678': 10, '696': 20, '978': 20 }
```

Obviously giving us the map of the array by telling which number is exists how many times.

Then I am re-mapping the array into a simpler form of objects and store it under `condense` as

```
[ { n: '978', c: 20 },
  { n: '696', c: 20 },
  { n: '678', c: 10 },
  { n: '446', c: 10 } ]
```

At this point we need to get the combinations of these objects, so that we can later solve all possibilities. For this task we are utilizing the `getCombinations()` utility function. It will result as follows;

```
[ [ { n: '978', c: 20 } ],
  [ { n: '696', c: 20 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 20 }, { n: '696', c: 20 } ],
  [ { n: '678', c: 10 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 20 }, { n: '678', c: 10 } ],
  [ { n: '696', c: 20 }, { n: '678', c: 10 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 20 }, { n: '696', c: 20 }, { n: '678', c: 10 } ],
  [ { n: '446', c: 10 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 20 }, { n: '446', c: 10 } ],
  [ { n: '696', c: 20 }, { n: '446', c: 10 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 20 }, { n: '696', c: 20 }, { n: '446', c: 10 } ],
  [ { n: '678', c: 10 }, { n: '446', c: 10 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 20 }, { n: '678', c: 10 }, { n: '446', c: 10 } ],
  [ { n: '696', c: 20 }, { n: '678', c: 10 }, { n: '446', c: 10 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 20 },
    { n: '696', c: 20 },
    { n: '678', c: 10 },
    { n: '446', c: 10 } ] ]
```

So now we know what we will try. But we have to try cleverly. We know the target sum being 6000 and we shouldn't allow excess calculations. Here comes the tricky part. We have the `getPossibles()` utility function which will return only the objects with the count (`c` property) values that can sum up or less than 6000. OK I have influenced from my [Array.prototype.cartesian()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39820324/4543207) tool which just works fine.

Ok `getPossibles()` will take an array of objects (condensed data) and will give us the possible combinations of sets with sums less than 6000. For instance for a combination of `[ { n: '978', c: 20 }, { n: '696', c: 20 }, { n: '678', c: 10 } ]` we would receive;

```
[ [ { n: '978', c: 5 }, { n: '696', c: 1 }, { n: '678', c: 0 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 4 }, { n: '696', c: 3 }, { n: '678', c: 0 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 4 }, { n: '696', c: 2 }, { n: '678', c: 1 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 4 }, { n: '696', c: 1 }, { n: '678', c: 2 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 3 }, { n: '696', c: 4 }, { n: '678', c: 0 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 3 }, { n: '696', c: 3 }, { n: '678', c: 1 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 3 }, { n: '696', c: 2 }, { n: '678', c: 2 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 3 }, { n: '696', c: 1 }, { n: '678', c: 3 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 2 }, { n: '696', c: 5 }, { n: '678', c: 0 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 2 }, { n: '696', c: 4 }, { n: '678', c: 1 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 2 }, { n: '696', c: 3 }, { n: '678', c: 2 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 2 }, { n: '696', c: 2 }, { n: '678', c: 3 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 2 }, { n: '696', c: 1 }, { n: '678', c: 4 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 1 }, { n: '696', c: 7 }, { n: '678', c: 0 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 1 }, { n: '696', c: 6 }, { n: '678', c: 1 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 1 }, { n: '696', c: 5 }, { n: '678', c: 2 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 1 }, { n: '696', c: 4 }, { n: '678', c: 3 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 1 }, { n: '696', c: 3 }, { n: '678', c: 4 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 1 }, { n: '696', c: 2 }, { n: '678', c: 5 } ],
  [ { n: '978', c: 1 }, { n: '696', c: 1 }, { n: '678', c: 6 } ] ]
```

Well... once you can have this data at hand then it's a simple matter of reducing what you have. So just one final line of;

```
possibles = combos.reduce((p,c) => (c.length > 1 ? p.push(...getPossibles(c,sum))
                                                 : p.push(getPossibles(c,sum)),p),[]);
                  .filter(p => p.reduce((s,o) => s += o.n*o.c,0) === sum)
                  .map(e => e.reduce((p,c) => p.concat(Array(c.c).fill(c.n)),[]));
```

is how we get the solution in less than 7msecs in JS.